# How do you move the uiimage inside the uiimageview to the right while retaining the aspect ratio of the original image?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to move an image to the right when a user imports it using uiimagepicker but when I set content mode = .right this occurs: [The image enlarges for some reason and it looks like it moves to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQeiZ.png)

Is there any way to keep the aspect ratio of the uiimageview and the aspect ratio of the imported image, and while also moving it to the right inside the image view.

[This is how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATFqI.jpg)

Comment: `UIImageView` does not have "aspectFIt and alignment" capability. You can accomplish this in a number of ways though... One is to use a subclassed view with an image view as a subview... search for `uiimageview aspect fit align` for lots of results. This one may work for you: https://github.com/sochalewski/UIImageViewAlignedSwift

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: custom view, using a sublayer with the content set to the image...

- add a `CALayer` as a sublayer
- calculate the aspect-scaled rectangle for the image inside the view's bounds
- set the image layer's frame to that scaled rect
- then set the layer's origin based on the desired alignment

A simple example:

```
class AspectAlignImageView: UIView {
    
    enum AspectAlign {
        case top, left, right, bottom, center
    }
    
    // this is an array so we can set two options
    //  if, for example, we don't know if the image will be
    //  taller or narrower
    //  for example:
    //      [.top, .right] will put a
    //          wide image aligned top
    //          narrow image aligned right
    public var alignment: [AspectAlign] = [.center]
    public var image: UIImage?
    
    private let imgLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // make sure we have an image
        if let img = image {
            // only add the sublayer once
            if imgLayer.superlayer == nil {
                layer.addSublayer(imgLayer)
            }
            imgLayer.contentsGravity = .resize
            imgLayer.contents = img.cgImage

            // calculate the aspect-scaled rect inside our bounds
            var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero
            let aspectWidth:CGFloat = bounds.width / img.size.width
            let aspectHeight:CGFloat = bounds.height / img.size.height
            let aspectRatio:CGFloat = min(aspectWidth, aspectHeight)
            scaledImageRect.size.width = img.size.width * aspectRatio
            scaledImageRect.size.height = img.size.height * aspectRatio

            // set image layer frame to aspect-scaled rect
            imgLayer.frame = scaledImageRect
            
            // align as specified
            if alignment.contains(.top) {
                imgLayer.frame.origin.y = 0
            }
            if alignment.contains(.left) {
                imgLayer.frame.origin.x = 0
            }
            if alignment.contains(.bottom) {
                imgLayer.frame.origin.y = bounds.maxY - scaledImageRect.height
            }
            if alignment.contains(.right) {
                imgLayer.frame.origin.x = bounds.maxX - scaledImageRect.width
            }
        }
    }
    
}

class TestAlignViewController: UIViewController {

    let testView = AspectAlignImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain test view 240x240 square
            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            // centered in view
            testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "bottle") {
            testView.image = img
        }
        testView.alignment = [.right]
    
        // so we can see the actual view frame
        testView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    
}
```

Using this image:

[image]

in a 240x240 view (view background set green so we can see its frame), we get this result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Set your UIImage Content mode to aspect fill or aspect fit. Then use auto layout.